# Sorting a Map in Java by Key

Tags: java, tuples, java-stream, treemap

I checked out some related questions but none answered my question. I'm trying to sort a Map ascending alphabetically, but am having issues. Here is the code currently:

```
    // provinceName is key
    public Map<String, String> regionMap() {
        return 
            em
            .createQuery(
                """
                SELECT DISTINCT p.provinceName AS prov_id ,p.provinceAbbreviation AS prov_value
                FROM CanadianPersonalIncomeTaxRate p         
                ORDER BY p.provinceName ASC
                """,
                Tuple.class
            )
            .getResultStream()
                //    .filter(prov_value -> prov_value.get())
                //    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(prov_value -> prov_value))
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    tuple -> tuple.get(0, String.class),
                    tuple -> tuple.get(1, String.class)
                )
            );
    }
```

I was thinking about using .sorted or TreeMap, but am open to suggestions on how I can do it the cleanest/simply. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just add some parameters to `toMap(..., (a, b) -> a, TreeMap::new)`

Comment: Looks like you’ve already asked the database to sort your data. Use a map that has a defined order - `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Why do you want to sort a hash map? General hash maps are used for storing data that doesn't have any intrinsic ordering. You may need to think about using a different data structure than a map if you care about the order.

Comment: For completeness, you should mention from what framework you are obtaining the `createQuery` & `getResultStream` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pass `TreeMap :: new`

Change the declaration of your result to indicate you want a map sorted by key. Use `NavigableMap`.

This:

```
public Map<String, String> regionMap() {
```

… should be:

```
public NavigableMap<String, String> regionMap() {
```

Specify a concrete implementation of `NavigableMap` by passing another argument, a map factory such as `TreeMap :: new`, to your `Collectors.toMap` call. We must also pass a merge function to decide what to do in case of duplicate elements. See the Javadoc for [this overload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) of `Collectors.toMap`.

```java
          Collectors.toMap(
                tuple -> tuple.get( 0 , String.class ) ,
                tuple -> tuple.get( 1 , String.class ) ,
                ( oldValue , newValue ) -> oldValue ) ,
                TreeMap :: new
            )
```

Your database sorting becomes superfluous in this approach. Since you are sorting on the Java side, you could delete the line of SQL:

```sql
ORDER BY p.provinceName ASC
```

But then again, adding elements to the `TreeMap` in pre-sorted order might help performance of the map’s sorting (just a guess on my part). So I would consider keeping the `ORDER BY`.

If you want to return an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable), use [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) with same arguments.

### Example code

Here is some example code.

First, some input data, to simulate your database query.

```java
String[][] inputs =
        {
                { "Ontario" , "ON" } ,
                { "Québec" , "QA" } ,
                { "Nova Scotia" , "NS" } ,
                { "New Brunswick" , "NB" } ,
                { "Manatob" , "MB" } ,
                { "British Columbia" , "BC" } ,
                { "Prince Edward Island" , "PE" } ,
                { "Saskatchewan" , "SK" } ,
                { "Alberta" , "AB" } ,
                { "Newfoundland and Labrador" , "NL" }
        };
```

And the logic. We retrieve each row from the array of arrays. We extract the first and second element from each row/array by zero-based index counting (`0` & `1`). And we collect those into a `NavigableMap`, specifically a `TreeMap`.

```java
NavigableMap < String, String > map =
        Arrays
                .stream( inputs )
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                ( String[] input ) -> input[ 0 ] ,
                                ( String[] input ) -> input[ 1 ] ,
                                ( String oldValue , String newValue ) -> oldValue ,
                                TreeMap :: new
                        )
                );
```

Or, if you don't need to see the type declarations, use the following. Your situation is complicated enough that I would personally retain the type declarations for clarity. Doing so would have prevented the error you made in naming `oldTuple , newTuple` when really it is the `String` value objects that are being merged, `oldValue, newValue`.

```java
NavigableMap < String, String > map =
        Arrays
                .stream( inputs )
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                input -> input[ 0 ] ,
                                input -> input[ 1 ] ,
                                ( oldValue , newValue ) -> oldValue ,
                                TreeMap :: new
                        )
                );
```

Result:

> map.toString() = {Alberta=AB, British Columbia=BC, Manatob=MB, New Brunswick=NB, Newfoundland and Labrador=NL, Nova Scotia=NS, Ontario=ON, Prince Edward Island=PE, Québec=QA, Saskatchewan=SK}

We can skip over unwanted rows.

- Add a call to [`Stream :: filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)).
- Pass a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html). Notice the `!` in our predicate. We are filtering for elements to *keep*, not *lose*.

```java
String[][] inputs =
        {
                { "Ontario" , "ON" } ,
                { "Federal" , "CAN" } ,  // <-- Unwanted row.
                { "Québec" , "QA" } ,
                { "Nova Scotia" , "NS" } ,
                { "New Brunswick" , "NB" } ,
                { "Manatob" , "MB" } ,
                { "British Columbia" , "BC" } ,
                { "Prince Edward Island" , "PE" } ,
                { "Saskatchewan" , "SK" } ,
                { "Alberta" , "AB" } ,
                { "Newfoundland and Labrador" , "NL" }
        };

NavigableMap < String, String > map =
        Arrays
                .stream( inputs )
                .filter( ( String[] input ) -> ! input[ 1 ].equalsIgnoreCase( "CAN" ) )
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                input -> input[ 0 ] ,
                                input -> input[ 1 ] ,
                                ( oldValue , newValue ) -> oldValue ,
                                TreeMap :: new
                        )
                );
```

Comment: `oldTuple` and `newTuple` are String values, not Tuples.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful and solved my issue. I have one more bug, one of my values is CAN that I want to ignore. It's the only value in the key value pair with 3 characters in the string instead of 2. Do you have any suggestions on how to remove value name from my return? @BasilBourque

Comment: @shmosel You are correct again. Fixed. Thank you again.

Comment: @CheckDeck I am curious, what province is `CAN`?

Comment: @CheckDeck Add a data element to my example, `{ "Federal" , "CAN" } ,`.  Add a call to `Stream::filter` like this: `.filter( ( String[] input ) -> ! input[ 1 ].equalsIgnoreCase( "CAN" ) )` before you call `.collect`.

Comment: @BasilBourque it's not a province, this program is iterating over tax info and so CAN holds federal tax info, but for this method I want to ignore it

Comment: You're an absolute legend @BasilBourque thanks again

Comment: @BasilBourque one more question for you if you don't mind. I'm using an Arquillian test to test this method, and want to return both the key and value for the first and last province. I Am currently returning the provinceName key, but I'm unsure how to extract the value pair to match as well. I've updated the question to show what my test currently looks like

Comment: @BasilBourque I figured out my issue, cheers

Comment: @CheckDeck Either a record or an enum (with member fields populated by arguments passed to a constructor) are two common ways to manage such data.

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap and LinkedHashMap are good candidates to serve the above requirement.

> A TreeMap is a map implementation that maintains the keys in sorted order.

```
return em.createQuery("""
            SELECT DISTINCT p.provinceName AS prov_id ,p.provinceAbbreviation AS prov_value
            FROM CanadianPersonalIncomeTaxRate p         
            ORDER BY p.provinceName ASC
            """, Tuple.class)
            .getResultStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    tuple -> tuple.get(0, String.class),
                    tuple -> tuple.get(1, String.class),
                    (a, b) -> a,TreeMap::new // use TreeMap to maintain sorted order
            ));
```

> LinkedHashMap instance to maintain the insertion order.

```
return em.createQuery("""
            SELECT DISTINCT p.provinceName AS prov_id ,p.provinceAbbreviation AS prov_value
            FROM CanadianPersonalIncomeTaxRate p         
            ORDER BY p.provinceAbbreviation ASC
            """, Tuple.class)
            .getResultStream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(tuple -> tuple.get(1, String.class))) // sort by value
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    tuple -> tuple.get(0, String.class),
                    tuple -> tuple.get(1, String.class),
                    (a, b) -> a,
                    LinkedHashMap::new // use LinkedHashMap to maintain insertion order
            ));
```